# Bash script for comparing numbers in columns

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a problem with writing a bash script and hope that someone can help me with this. 
I have written a few smaller scripts in bash before, so I'm not totally new, but there's still lots of space for improvement.

So, I have a file that only contains two columns of decimal numbers, like:

```
0.46    0.68
0.92    1.36
1.38    2.04
1.84    2.72
 2.3    3.4
2.76    4.08
3.22    4.76
3.68    5.44
4.14    6.12
...
```

What I want to do is to compare every number in the first column with every number in the second column and check, if any two numbers are equal and print this number then to the screen or a file.

I found an answer for how to do this in an excel table, but I would be really interested in how to do this in bash or maybe with awk.

The first problem for me is that I don't even know how I would compare the first number to all others in the second column. 
I guess that I would have to do this via arrays. I could read the two numbers by a 'while read var_1 var_2' command and then I would have to somehow add var_1 of each line to an array_1, same for var_2 for another array_2 and then I somehow would have to compare all the elements with each other.

But I don't know how to. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Are you looking for string or numeric equality? I mean if "2.4" appeared in column 1 and "2.40" in column 2 - are those equal or not?

Comment: @ Ed Morton: I'm looking for numerical equality, so 2.4 = 2.40.

Comment: The the script you selected as the correct answer won't work for you as it is testing for string equality since in awk all array indices are strings.

Comment: You might be right, I'm not an expert with awk and just assumed that this would still happen for the answer I chose as the right one. Nevertheless it still works for me, because a case like 2.4 and 2.40 will never appear in my lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk`

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]++;next} ($2 in a) {print $2}' file file
4.08
1.38
```

Read the file and store column #1 in array `a`, then compare column #2 with array `a`

```
cat file
0.46    0.68
0.92    1.36
1.38    2.04
1.84    2.72
 2.3    3.4
2.76    4.08
3.22    4.76
3.68    5.44
4.14    6.12
4.08    1.38
```

Answer (score 1):

this line should work:

```
 awk '{a[$1]=1;b[$2]}END{for(x in b){a[x]++;if(a[x]>1)print x}}' file
```

note that the loop and check in END is for excluding the duplicated numbers in same column. if each col has unique numbers, that part could be simplified.

with fedorqui's example, the output is:

```
4.08
1.38
```

```
cat file
0.46    0.68
0.92    1.36
1.38    2.04
1.84    2.72
 2.3    3.4
2.76    4.08
3.22    4.76
3.68    5.44
4.14    6.12
4.08    1.38
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. It works, but the order numbers in the output is messed up, so it's difficult to find the lowest value.

Comment: @user3197817 why this answer and Jotne's give same output, one works "perfectly" one "messed up" ?

Comment: The output is the same, that's true, but the order is different. Jotne's output is sorted with the smallest number at the top and this is for me more convenient.

Comment: @user3197817 I pressed `F5` and checked his answer, not sorted. also, in awk, if you use `for(x in array)` there is NO sorting happening. both answers are the same. If you want to have a sorted you could either do the sort in awk, or just pipe the output to `sort`.

Comment: Hm, I just copied his awk line into my terminal and redirected the input to it and it gives me the numbers starting with the smallest and ending with the highest: 15, 31, 46, 62, and so on.

Comment: When I copy your command into my terminal the numbers are disordered: 62, 140, 172, 15, and so on... I don't know why it appears different

Comment: @user3197817 as I said, awk's `x in array` won't grantee the order of element. it is not predictable. This is well documented. it may give "sorted" result for some input, but it is not always working in that way.

Answer (score 1):

one line, converting to one column, sort and use uniq to print only duplicates:

```
(awk '{print $1}' test_input|sort|uniq  ; awk '{print $2}' test_input|sort|uniq)|sort|uniq -d
```

Comment: `converting to one column, sort and use uniq` is not a good idea. what if there are duplicates in same col? apart from the `awk;awk;sort;uniq`

Comment: @Kent thx for comment, I've added uniq to remove duplicates in one column but you are true that there are many utilities in the chain

Comment: I saw the `uniq`, it removes the dups in the combination of col1 and col2. what I meant was, E.g. in col1 there are four `foo`, but in col2, there is no `foo` at all. so `foo` should not be in output.

Comment: @Kent the sort|uniq can be used also to remove duplicates from one column but it is now crazy complicated, I agree.

Answer (score 0):

A bash solution that works the way you described:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read c1 c2 ;do
    c1a=("${c1a[@]}" "$c1")
    c2a=("${c2a[@]}" "$c2")
done < numbers.txt

for c1 in ${c1a[@]} ;do
    for c2 in ${c2a[@]} ;do
        [[ $c1 == $c2 ]] && echo $c1
    done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk without read the file two times.

```
awk '{a[$1];b[$2];for (i in b) if (i in a) {print i;delete a[i];delete b[i]}}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{ a[$1]; b[$2] }
END{
    for (x in a) {
        for (y in b) {
            if (x+0 == y) {
                print x
                break
            }
        }
    }
}' file
```